# Meanings of terminal codes \033[E and \033[07, which appear in printf() statements?

Tags: terminal, ansi-escape

In the C implementation for the Game of Life program, as shown [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life#C) the codes I mentioned appear in the `show()` function. I can't find any information at all about what `033[E` means and as for `\033[07` this is usually a color code in linux bash terminal, where with \033[07**m** we begin the color coding and with \033[**m** we end the predefined color coding. However, according to [this](https://godoc.org/github.com/Xuyuanp/glogger/formatters) website it means "reverse". I'm not sure what that means.

I'm more interested though in `\033[E` code, for which I can find no information. From testing and debugging the program with gcc on Linux bash, I see that without this command, the output is not displayed as intended. If anyone can share knowledge on this, I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: google "ansi escape codes".

Comment: Did you google the exact title of the question?

Comment: @WeatherVane: That's unhelpful. Stackoverflow always ranks very high in google search results. So, if someone googles this question next week, they will get your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Lucas: Not if the question is deleted.

Comment: @Lucas which keywords in my previous comment had anything to do with a search of the question topic? Should I have googled it for him? But I will give a better answer: the octal number `033` is the decimal number `27`, that is, the escape sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence `ESC [ E` is an error – or possibly, a hypercorrect version – in that source. The code is `ESC E`, and it serves to move the cursor to [the next line](http://www.vt100.net/docs/vt510-rm/chapter4.html). The `[` indicates it can take an optional numerical parameter (*zero* or more), and in this case there are none, so it can be omitted. (A numerical parameter would indicate how many lines to skip; `0` or `1` shows a regular newline, and higher values makes it skip lines.)

The definition is hard to find because it's more usual to just use `\n` – the regular newline code – to move the cursor to the start of the next line in a terminal program.

The sequence `ESC [07m` also contains a redundant code, `ESC [7m` is enough to put the terminal into Reverse mode. You are probably used to adding this to the start of a color sequence so you can set the *foreground color* of the text (numbers from `30..37`) instead of *background* (`40..47`), and use spaces to draw a colored block.

Comment: It's not exactly the same as `\n`. The escape sequence `\033[nE` (where `n` is a number) can be used to move more than one line at a time and (at least on some terminals) will go no further than the bottom of the console window (i.e., it won't initiate scrolling).

Comment: @squeamishossifrage: thanks, reworded that. Do you have a good source? The page I link to does not mention it.

Comment: There's a reasonably comprehensive list in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes). I can't find any sources that mention the lack of scrolling, but this is how Ubuntu and OS X behave.

Comment: I don't understand why 033 is ESC(ape). Since the ASCII code for esc is 27 and 33 (decimal) signifies the exclamation mark (!). But i'll keep looking.

Comment: @RestlessC0bra: It's basic C string notation. It is not decimal, it's *octal*, as indicated by the leading `\0`. And so `033` to decimal is 3*8 + 3 = 27.

Comment: @RadLexus Another thing. What is terminal Reverse mode? You didn't explain that. You said that it is used to set the foreground color, instead of the background, is that right?. However i didn't set the color anywhere..

Comment: @RestlessC0bra: it reverses forground and background colors. Try it with setting fore- and background, print a few characters, then reverse, and then some characters again.