# Overwrite Multiple Terminal Lines

Tags: c, windows, terminal

I'm trying to make a simple 16*16 terminal display for a C project that uses something like this loop:

```
for(i = 1; i <= 256; i++) {
    printf("%c ", output[i-1]);
    if(i % 16 == 0) {
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

To display something like this (but twice as big):

```
* * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * *
```

The problem is, this obviously just prints a new display *below* the previous one each time the display is refreshed, when I need to print *over* it instead. The carriage return `\r` only writes over the previous line, while I need to write over the previous 16.

Is there any way to do this in C? I'm using Windows so I don't know if ncurses is an option.

Comment: You probably want to work with the actual *terminal*, not just the opaque standard output stream. Terminal control is platform-specific, so consult your vendor documentation (Windows, I suppose). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138153/is-ncurses-available-for-windows.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I found a solution.

Comment: If the Windows console support ANSI escape codes, you can look at the source code pointed to by [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41485511/2564301) - it positions the cursor at the top of the screen without clearing it first.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a library that can handle terminals. One such library is [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)

Answer (score -2):

Okay I got it: on windows `system("cls")` clears the terminal. It clears all of it instead of just 16 lines, but it does the job.